# PHP: Public Function variable isn't visible outside

Tags: function, variables, public

here is the sample code:

```
    class PeoplePDF extends TFPDF {
    // Create basic table
    public $test;
    public function CreateTable($header, $data)
    {

        foreach ($header as $col) {
            $this->Cell($col[1], 8, $col[0], 1, 0, 'C', true);
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Data
        $this->SetFillColor(255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','','9');

        $date = date('d/m/y', strtotime($row["SendDate"]));

        //$allRowsCount = count($data);

        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Service;', 'root', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $sqlNum = $db->prepare("select * From actnumbers");
        $sqlNum->execute();
        $sqlNumResult = $sqlNum->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $lastnumber = $sqlNumResult[0]["LastNumber"];
        //$this->test = $sqlNumResult[0]["ActNumber"];
        $this->test = "test";

        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $date = date('d/m/y', strtotime($row["SendDate"])); 
               $this->Cell($header[0][1], 6, $lastnumber, 1, 0, 'C', true);             
        }


    }
}

$myObj = new PeoplePDF ();
$test = $myObj->test;
echo $test; //it's not visible. echoes nothing
```

I know I have a very stupid mistake.
I am newbie in this. )
I guess I am not declaring the variable $test correctly;
how can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
class PeoplePDF extends TFPDF {
public $test;

  public function CreateTable($header, $data){ 

    $this->test = "test";

  }

}
```

outside the class you can use it like this

```
$myObj = new PeoplePDF ();
$test = $myObj->test;
```

Comment: it's not working :( I still cant echo variable outside

Comment: Did you call CreateTable first to set the $test variable? can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Thanks Dola, for response.
I've edited the question and inserted my actual code.